# Should we rename [tmnt] to [teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

[tmnt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tmnt) (21 Q) does *not* show up on a search for 'teenage' while asking a question, nor is [teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles) a synonym or anything. If I hadn't clicked on a [tmnt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tmnt) question, I would have no idea what tag to use when asking a Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles question.

**Can we rename [tmnt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tmnt) to [teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles)?**

Comment: why not just set up a synonym?

Comment: @phantom42 Because I'm fairly sure that [teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles] is a better tag name than [tmnt].

Answer (score 23):

### No

Unfortunately, it's too long. `teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles` has 28 characters, which is 3 over the limit. You could try it without the dashes, but that makes for an ugly tag.

What we *could* probably do, is set up [teenagemutantninjaturtles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teenagemutantninjaturtles), the ugly no-dash version, as a synonym for [tmnt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tmnt), so that it will be found when searching for tags, but [tmnt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tmnt) will be used.

While we're at it, we might as well set up [teenagemutantheroturtles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teenagemutantheroturtles) and [tmht](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tmht) as synonyms.

Comment: Do synonyms have a length restriction?

Comment: Yeah tag synonym have the same character limitation as tags.

Comment: [Done](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/tmnt/synonyms).

Comment: Worth mentioning TMHT as an alias aswell, one of the old old old versions of TMNT (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Py0QpvvJl_s)

Comment: May as well also create a tag for `teenagemuntentninjatoitles`.  Rocksteady and Beebop will gladly point out that it is a shorter number of characters.  (After figuring out just how much it saves, remember to thank Rocksteady and Beebop for being the ones who will happily tell you this.)

Comment: It is now possible to rename [tmnt] due to the new 35 character extension.

Answer (score 8):

### We can now rename it

[All sites are now allowed to use tags with 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/191265). Thus we can rename this tag to [teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles).

Comment: Aaaaaaand done.

Answer (score 2):

TMNT is the accepted abbreviation for the franchise, to the point that one of the movies was specifically titled [TMNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMNT_(film)). It's pretty clear what it means. Even a Google search for TMNT brings up "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles" first thing.

However, the other short name, [ninja-turtles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ninja-turtles), would make a good synonym.

Comment: There's not much point in creating a [ninja-turtles] tag and merging it with [tmnt], because as soon as you type "ninja", [tmnt] will come up via autocomplete because it's a synonym of [teenagemutant**ninja**turtles].